# Is there any alternative to genext2fs in RHEL?

Tags: linux, kernel, rhel, compiling, ext2

I am tryting to make initrd file system following [this tutorial][1]

My host system is RHEL 6 64 bit.

I am unable to get the required command: `genext2fs`

No rpm is available for it, neither yum  is helping me.

I hope there is an alternate to this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want [genext2fs](http://genext2fs.sourceforge.net/), it's easy to find; build it from source. But you probably don't want it. Create an initramfs instead. That's the normal method these days.

Comment: I compiled from source.